# What is the Stack Exchange OpenID URL?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

I know the answer to this question is here somewhere, I've even found it once or twice before, but I'm tired of searching for it for 10 minutes every time. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's https://openid.stackexchange.com/.